# Analysing discrete data from a factorial experimental design

Tags: anova, assumptions, discrete-data

The dependent variable in my data can take on the values 0-7 and is, therefore, a discrete variable. I have data from a number of experiments with one, two, and three-way factorial designs.

The previous literature on my topic has just used ANOVA of analyse this type of data. This seems clearly wrong to me and my data rarely meet the assumptions of ANOVA which suggests all the published research on this topic has used the wrong statistical models.

My issue is that I don't know what the best approach to analysing this data is. What is the most appropriate model for analysing discrete data using a factorial design? I'm using R to analyse the data.

Comment: I guess some form of a generalized linear model might be appropriate but I don't know enough about this form of models.

Answer (score 2):

Given that prior research has analyzed comparable data using ANOVA, I am assuming that the 8-point scale is at least ordinal. That it is discrete is not problematic. Does this scale measure a latent characteristic that is continuous or is it measuring something that only takes on these eight values? Can you assume, even if only roughly, that there are equal intervals between the levels of the scale? What is your sample size and is the sample size balanced across conditions? Answers to all of these questions effects whether an ANOVA approach is "clearly wrong" as you state or a reasonable approach, even if not strictly ideal.

Recall that given the Central Limit Theorem, as sample size increases, the sampling distribution becomes normal even with data from a population that is non-normally distributed. This also extends to discretized data (hence the ability to use a z-test on proportions given a large sample size -- although with modern computers there is little to no need to do so). A consequence of this is that ANOVA (or OLS regression) will often produce results that are in agreement with more complex models with assumptions that more closely match the data, such as an ordered logistic regression model.

Thus, an ANOVA approach is not "clearly wrong" even if it is not precisely correct. I recommend that you compare the results from an ANOVA model to an ordered logistic regression model. For the ordered logistic regression model, take care in how you parameterize your factors and interactions. I recommend effect coding to get a model that more closely aligns with a simple ANOVA model. If the design isn't balanced, you also need to build the model in stages to simulate a Type II sums-of-squares analysis. If the ordered logistic regression model and ANOVA lead to comparable substantive interpretations, go with the latter as it is easier to interpret and easier for most readers to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. In the context of my experiments, the data can only take on these values. I'm measuring is the number of references to a piece of target information that people make across 7 questions. So, yes, the intervals between each level of the scale are equal. My group sizes do also differ to some extent (in one experiment they vary between 16-25). If the ordered logistic regression model and ANOVA models lead to comparable interpretations do I need to account for the non-normal residuals, heteroscedastic error variance, and unbalanced groups in some way?

Comment: Given that your DV is a count, why not use a Poison model? That said, unless your residuals and other diagnostic suggest a problem, ANOVA should be fine

Comment: Yes, the residuals are non-normal and heteroscedastic. One thing I considered was using a generalized linear model including a term that allows for unequal variances but this doesn't deal with the non-normal residuals. I will look into Poisson models as well.

Comment: In a Poisson distribution, the variance increases as the count increases. Thus, if your heteroscedasticity is increasing variance within increasing count, then the Poisson model may fix this.

Comment: OK, great I will check this out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi again, I tried the Poisson model but it seems as if there is overdispersion and excess zeros in my data so a zero-inflated model is more appropriate. It looks like the results I get are slightly different from the linear model/ANOVA. There doesn't appear to be a lot of guidance for interpreting the output from these models (particularly when there are interaction terms involved) and I fear that I won't be able to do a good job of this. Do you know if there is a legitimate transformation that I could apply to fit the linear model to my data so that the results are  easier to interpret?

Comment: With zero-inflated count data, there is no transformation that will normalize it (with any transformation, the value with the largest frequency will always be at the far left of the distribution). There is good information on the web, such as the https://stats.idre.ucla.edu website, for interpreting such models. With unbalanced data, the interactions are tricky. Run a model with and without them. Base any interpretation of the main effects from the former and interactions from the latter.

Comment: Great thanks for all this information it's been very helpful. I've been reading up on this a little (serious stats by Thom Baguley) has a chapter on modeling discrete outcomes and this says that an assumption of Poisson models is that counts are independent. I don't think this is the case with my data since each person answers all 7 questions and the count is whether or not they refer to a piece of info on that question. Do you have any suggestions in this instance?

Comment: My understanding is that you have one count (from 0 to 7) for each individual and that the individuals are independent. Is that not the case? I think more details on what you actually did are needed.

Comment: Individuals are independent. They answer 7 questions. For each question, they are scored a 1 if they refer to a piece of target info on that question. Then each participant has a total score which tells me on how many questions they referred to the target info.

Comment: You are right that the responses within an individual are not independent but that is not the issue. What matters is that each count is independent, which it is.